# How do play a video file in a ruby project?

Tags: ruby, video-streaming, jruby

I found a rvideo library but manual very small and I'm learning ruby one day.
I need play a video in window. How have me done it? There is possibility cause the video player from a ruby code? or have any other way done my task?

Comment: Are you trying to play a video in a web browser,OS defualt video player, or within your own ruby GUI app

Comment: Target OS android(jruby, rubuto). Now I'm doing in a ruby in a debian. `system( "dragon /home/knowill/work/r/input.mp4" )`
trying `gem install hornetseye-frame` but get error `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first thing I would do is install [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) and follow the instructions which should tell you what other packages you need to install, the error you received is cause you don't have the build-essential installed.  per rvm  you need to install

> rvm requirements
>   ...
>
> ## For Ruby / Ruby HEAD (MRI, Rubinius, & REE), install the following:
>
> ruby: /usr/bin/apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev 
>   curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev
>   libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkgconfig

After RVM is installed with the packages you need, go ahead and install the flavors or Ruby you need.

Unfortunately Rubuto isn't a subsitute for learning the andriod API, the revelevent API that you need is here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html you will just need to make the right API calls and references in your Rubuto/JRUBY project